# Diluted EPS Calculation

Tags: stocks, shares, stock-valuation, price-earnings-ratio, earnings-per-share

I'm new to Capital Markets and Balance Sheet reading. I'm trying to calculate DEPS (Diluted EPS) using data available in https://www.screener.in

**Diluted EPS = (Net Income−Preferred Dividends​) / Total Outstanding Share + CDS** (Conversion of Dilute Securities)

I managed to get the

- Net Income
- Dividends
- Total Outstanding Share

But Not able to figure out how to get the **CDS**.

Can any one please assist me how to calculate this and what are the particulars used to get this value.
It'll be very helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

Diluted earnings per share (EPS) is normally calculated with the following [formula](https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/051115/what-difference-between-earnings-share-eps-and-diluted-eps.asp):

**Diluted EPS = Net income – Dividends on preferred stock/ (Weighted average number of outstanding shares + Conversion of diluted securities)**

In order to calculate the [CDS](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/convertible-security.asp), you have to take the number of convertible shares and multiply it by the [conversion ratio](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/conversionprice.asp), which is the ratio or percentage at which the convertible security can be converted to common stock.

Here's an very simplified example: A convertible bond's conversion ratio is 10. The bond's [par value](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/parvalue.asp) (amount listed on the face of the bond) is $10,000. The bond's conversion price is $1,000 ($10,000 / 10). This, plus the conversion prices of all other dilutive securities, should be the number you use for CDS. Sometimes the conversion ratio will be the interest rate on the bonds or some other type of percentage. For example, in order to calculate diluted EPS from 5% interest, you would have to multiply by 0.05. Conversion of diluted securities is basically showing investors what would happen if certain outstanding securities were converted into common stock. Such a conversion would affect the earnings per share (EPS) by diluting (lowering) the actual EPS.

[This article](https://corporatefinanceinstitute.com/resources/knowledge/valuation/diluted-shares/) shows how to find diluted EPS from a company's balance sheet. And [this article](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3AXKOPhlnBPvkJ%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.educba.com%2Fdiluted-earnings-per-share%2F%20&cd=19&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-b-1-d) gives a very detailed analysis of how diluted EPS is calculated on a company's balance sheet.

Comment: I think you need parentheses around "Net income – Dividends on preferred stock".